Finding library versions inside docker image amazoncorretto:11.0.23-alpine3.18
Could you please help me to find the version of libraries used inside amazoncorretto:11.0.23-alpine3.18
I need to find mx4j and sjsxp versions, I am using corona scanner for finding vulnerability in my application and these are reported as having unknown versions:
The path mentioned for these are:
mx4j:
usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/jmods/java.management.jmod/classes/javax/management
sjsxp:
usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/jmods/java.xml.jmod/classes/com/sun
For other libraries I ran the application and found using find command in linux
as:
`find / -name "*library*"` 
but I am unable to find for these . I even tried downloading amazon-coretto-11 jdk zip but couldnt find any relevant information
Please help me to find the version of these unknown libraries inside the docker image.

In your Dockerfile, how do you install these libraries?  What would you do with the version information once you found it?

Check the Java module version:
docker run --rm amazoncorretto:11.0.23-alpine3.18 java --list-modules

or check the OpenJDK 11 version:
docker run --rm amazoncorretto:11.0.23-alpine3.18 java -version


I am getting list of java modules of 11.0.23 but Nothing related to mentioned libraries
